# Print BING Map Location in the PDF programmatically

Tags: c#, silverlight, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf-generation, bing-maps

I am using Silverlight BING Map Api to show the location (by providing the address) on my website..

And I want to show this Map location in the PDF file programmatically, I tried alot using 'wkhtmltopdf' but all in-vain, It shows empty space instead of BING MAP...

Please guide me in this case, I am open in using any other open source PDF generation tool.

Thanks
Xtremist

Answer (score 2):

If you want insert image to PDF use [iText library](http://itextpdf.com/examples/iia.php?id=183). It is very easy to start using it:

```
        string pdfFilename = @"c:\temp\test.pdf";
        string imageFilename = @"C:\map.jpg";

        // Create PDF writer, document and image to put
        iTextSharp.text.Image image = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(imageFilename);
        Document doc = new Document();
        PdfWriter pdfW = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(pdfFilename, FileMode.Create));

        // Open created PDF and insert image to it
        doc.Open();
        doc.Add(image);
        doc.Close();
```

Or do you want to save Bing map as image?

Comment: Currently I have silverlight BING map object (just like flash animation) on my website. First I want to save Bing map as image and then print that image in PDF (using any open source).

Comment: Then combine mine and **Chris Haas** methods and you'll get it :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there's an easy way to do it through the Silverlight SDK. Instead, I think Microsoft prefers that you use the [Bing Maps SOAP Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966738.aspx). Specifically you'll want to look at the [Imagery Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc981090.aspx) where you can send a [`ImageryMetadataRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc966950.aspx) with location/zoom info set in the [`ImageryMetadataOptions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980899.aspx). Some basic sample code can be found [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc980855.aspx).

Once you get the images you can pretty easily add them to a PDF.